# Trouble with Python ReadWriteMemory

Tags: python

This is my code so far. I am using ReadWriteMemory for python.

```
import time
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

def main():
    # getting Procces
    rwm = ReadWriteMemory()
    process = rwm.get_process_by_name("Among Us.exe")
    process.open()
    print(f"Process Information: {process.__dict__}")

    # declaring pointers | Among Us.exe -> 00350000
    baseaddress_speed = 0x00350000 + 0x01F8FD0C
    speed_pointer = process.get_pointer(baseaddress_speed, offsets=[0x5C, 0x14, 0x8])
    
    # get current values
    current_speed = process.read(speed_pointer)
    print(f"Current Speed: {current_speed}")

    # set new values
    new_speed = 4

    # write new values
    process.write(speed_pointer, new_speed)

    # closing Process
    process.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Problem is that i get a value of 0 for the speed, but my pointer is valid.
The Problem is that the pointer has the module `"GameAssembly.dll"`
Her a picture:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAuqq.png

How can I add this to my code so it references to the "GameAssembly.dll"

Answer (score 0):

(i think this might help)

by putting "0x00350000" as a baseaddress you are putting the base address of "amongus.exe" instead of "GameAssembly.dll".

What i do is copy what's in the picture, add address manually in CE and paste it, once added, in the "address" space there will be a series of numbers and letters, or just numbers.

so you open the windows calculator in programmer mode, choose hex, and write that number. Then, you subtract "01F8FD0C" and the result is the base address of "GameAssembly.dll".

Try that and tell me if it worked. Best regards.